# Docker Compose Configuration for Jupyter Notebook Connecting to Remote MySQL Server

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on a project where I need to run a Jupyter Notebook within a Docker container and connect to a remote MySQL server for data analysis. I'm looking for guidance on how to set up the Docker Compose configuration for this specific scenario.

Here are the key details of my project:

- I have a remote MySQL server with the following details:

  - Host: `mysql.example.com`
  - Port: `3306`
  - Database: `mydb`
  - User: `myuser`
  - Password: `mypassword`
- I have created a Dockerfile for my Jupyter Notebook environment, and it's already up and running on my local machine. Here's the simplified `docker-compose.yml` configuration:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  jupyter:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
      - "3307:3306"   # Problematic ???
    volumes:
      - ./notebooks:/app
```

I would like to know how to configure the `docker-compose.yml` file to run the Jupyter Notebook container and set up the necessary network connections to connect to the remote MySQL server for data retrieval and analysis.

Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on how to:

1. Define a service for the Jupyter Notebook container.
2. Set up the network connection so that the Jupyter container can connect to the remote MySQL server.
3. Specify the necessary environment variables or configuration for the MySQL connection within the Jupyter container.